# The connections of the redefined Winapi structures with their original state?

Tags: c++, winapi, struct

I'm aim to understand WinApi struct redefine. But I don't find any documentation, reference or manual in anywhere. Please explain me, how is related to redefine struct to its original form, in the example below. Does the compiler understand the name of the redefined structure and establish a relationship with the PEB_LDR_DATA structure?

Here is the original PEB_LDR_DATA structure:

```
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA {
  BYTE       Reserved1[8];
  PVOID      Reserved2[3];
  LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;
```

And here is the PEB_LDR_DATA redefined structure MY_PEB_LDR_DATA:

```
typedef struct _MY_PEB_LDR_DATA {
    ULONG Length;
    BOOL Initialized;
    PVOID SsHandle;
    LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
} MY_PEB_LDR_DATA, * PMY_PEB_LDR_DATA;
```

Comment: At runtime there's only bytes and byte offsets in the struct. Both happen to match, assuming 8 byte pointers. Probably the easiest is to create both structures and inspect them in a debugger

Comment: no any *original* form. in *c/c++* you can define `PEB_LDR_DATA` (from *winternl.h* ) and *MY_PEB_LDR_DATA* (truncated `_PEB_LDR_DATA` from *pdb* ). from compiler view this is different structures. but `InMemoryOrderModuleList` **have the same offset** in both (in bot 32 and 64 bit code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please explain me, how is related to redefine struct to its original form

In memory, both structs have the same layout, assuming they both use the same data alignment settings for their respective fields.

`PEB_LDR_DATA::Reserved1` is an array holding 8 bytes.  `ULONG` and `BOOL` are 4 bytes each, thus the offset of `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA::Length` is the same as `PEB_LDR_DATA::Reserved1[0]`, and the offset of `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA::Initialized` is the same as `PEB_LDR_DATA::Reserved1[4]`.

`PEB_LDR_DATA::Reserved2` is an array holding 3 `void*` pointers. The offset of `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA::SsHandle` is the same as `PEB_LDR_DATA::Reserved2[0]`.  [`LIST_ENTRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdef/ns-ntdef-list_entry) is a struct that holds 2 `LIST_ENTRY*` pointers, thus the offset of `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA::InLoadOrderModuleList::Flink` is the same as `PEB_LDR_DATA::Reserved2[1]`, and the offset of `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA::InLoadOrderModuleList::Blink` is the same as `PEB_LDR_DATA::Reserved2[2]`.

Thus leaving the offset of `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA::InMemoryOrderModuleList` as the same as `PEB_LDR_DATA::InMemoryOrderModuleList`.

And so on for the rest of the `PEB_LDR_DATA` and `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA` fields.

> Does the compiler understand the name of the redefined structure and establish a relationship with the PEB_LDR_DATA structure?

No.  They are separate and distinct types, with no relation between them at all, as far as the compiler is concerned.  However, if they are setup properly, then given a pointer to a block of memory holding a `PEB_LDR_DATA`, you can type-cast that pointer and access the data *as-if* the memory were holding a `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA` instead.  This is the strength (and danger) of type-casting pointers.

Comment: *"However, if they are setup properly, then given a pointer to a block of memory holding a `PEB_LDR_DATA`, you can type-cast that pointer and access the data as-if the memory were holding a `MY_PEB_LDR_DATA` instead."* - That's usually correct in practice, though the behavior of this cast is strictly undefined. *"In memory, both structs have the same layout, assuming they both use the same data alignment settings for their respective fields."* - You can have the compiler enforce those assumptions using `static_assert` with `offsetof` expressions.

Comment: Thank you for explanatory answer. I'm understood this subject.